# Dashcode code translation

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, dashcode, iphone-web-app

a quick, probably easy question whose answer is probably "best practice"

I'm following a tutorial for a custom-template mobile Safari webapp, and to change views around this code is used:

```
function btnSave_ClickHandler(event)
{
    var views = document.getElementById('stackLayout');
    var front = document.getElementById('mainScreen');
    if (views && views.object && front) {
        views.object.setCurrentView(front, true);
    }
}
```

My question is just about the `if` conditional statement. What is this triplet saying, and why do each of those things need to be verified before the view can be changed? Does `views.object` just test to see if the views variable responds to the object method? Why is this important?

**EDIT** - This is/was the main point of this question, and it regards not Javascript as a language and how `if` loops work, but rather WHY these 3 things specifically need to be checked:

**Under what scenarios might `views` and `front` not exist?**

I don't typically write my code so redundantly. If the name of my MySQL table isn't changing, I'll just say `UPDATE 'mytable' WHERE...` instead of the much more verbose (and in my view, redundant)

```
$mytable = "TheSQLTableName";
if ($mytable == an actual table && $mytable exists && entries can be updated){
    UPDATE $mytable;
}
```

Whereas if the table's name (or in the JS example, the view's names) ARE NOT "hard coded" but are instead a user input or otherwise mutable, I might right my code as the DashCode example has it. So tell me, can these values "go wrong" anyhow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if is testing those 3 pointers to make sure they are non-null.  A null pointer is 0 which converts to false.  If any of those 3 pointer are 0 (null) then it won't try to use them.

I'm not sure what dereferencing a null pointer does in Javascript but it's an error and may cause an exception.  The if is just avoiding that possibility.